# Issue on getting data from Webservices

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, web-services, ios8

Here i get the data from WebServices,but i need individual keys data.the below format what i am getting on WebServices.

```
 {
    aps =     {
        alert = "{\"user_id\":\"92\",\"ref_id\":\"58\",\"ref_name\":\"name\",\"date\":\"2015-04-23\",\"time\":\"16:27\",\"lat\":\"17.409769\",\"lon\":\"78.460849\",\"msg\":\"text message here\"}";
        sound = default;
    };
```

here i get `NSMutableDictionary`

```
  NSMutableDictionary*  json =[userInfo valueForKey:@"aps"];
        NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

on the json i get,

```
     {
         alert = "{\"user_id\":\"92\",\"ref_id\":\"58\",\"ref_name\":\"name\",\"date\":\"2015-04-23\",\"time\":\"16:27\",\"lat\":\"17.409769\",\"lon\":\"78.460849\",\"msg\":\"text message here\"}";
  sound = default;
}
```

Here get the `alert`

```
 NSDictionary* json=[json valueForKey:@"alert"];
        NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

now i get the response like this,

```
{
        "user_id": "92",
        "ref_id": "58",
        "ref_name": "Name",
        "date": "2015-04-23",
        "time": "15:30",
        "lat": "17.409769",
        "lon": "78.460849",
        "msg": "Text message here"
    }
```

but i will try get `msg` key,here i developed code like this,

```
  NSString *msg=[json objectForKey:@"msg"];
            NSLog(@"%@",msg);
```

the problem i am not getting `msg` key ,and the error message is

```
reason: '[<__NSCFString 0x15e4ab10> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key msg.'
```

how can i get NSCFString from WebServices,can you please suggest me how can i out here,Thank you.

Comment: What's `Json`, what's `json`? What's logged exactly?

Comment: Try to print all keys of your Json content and check "msg" key is there or not !!

Comment: i tried all keys but it's not working @vivek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code..

```
NSString *str = @"{\"Json\":{\"user_id\":\"92\",\"ref_id\":\"58\",\"ref_name\": \"Name\",\"date\": \"2015-04-23\",\"time\": \"15:30\",\"lat\": \"17.409769\",\"lon\":\"78.460849\",\"msg\": \"Text message here\"}}";
NSError *jsonError;
NSData *objectData = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:objectData
                                                     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                       error:&jsonError];
NSLog(@"%@",[json objectForKey:@"Json"]);

NSDictionary *dict = [json objectForKey:@"Json"];

NSLog(@"%@",[dict objectForKey:@"msg"]);

NSString *mesg =[dict objectForKey:@"msg"];

NSLog(@"%@", mesg);
```

Comment: What is the problem in my code? Can you please tell me? its working for me.. As per his requirements.

Comment: If I am making any mistake. Please edit my code and correct me. It would be help for me in future. :) Please.

Comment: enjoy dude.. Thanks for appreciation :)

Answer (score -2):

if you want to print msg just use your code like this

```
NSString* mesg=[Json valueForKey:@"msg"];
    NSLog(@"%@",mesg);
```

or else tell me clearly what you want to do exactly?

Comment: i need only mesg data from the services.@deepak

Answer (score -2):

You are doing wrong actually try the below.

```
NSData *data =  "Your response data";
NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error = nil;
NSMutableDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                                options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                                                                  error:&error];
```

Now check "jsonDict" values, and tell ?

Comment: Can u print what "jsonDict" contains ?